# How should I ask a question regarding a celebrity's political stance?

Tags: discussion, scope

Title says most of it. The original question was put on hold and then deleted without comments on anything, which I consider to be pretty bad form.

As celebrity endorsements are certainly part of the overall campaign process in the USA, I'm unsure how my original question was off-topic. Furthermore, like most SE questions, this should have an answer and be something that can be provided a clear yes or no backed up with reputable sources.

Alternately, is there a better SE location for this? Skeptics seemed like an alternate possibility.

Original question: [Does Chris Pratt Support President Trump?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18953/does-chris-pratt-support-president-trump) Text for those who can't see it:

> **Does Chris Pratt Support President Trump?**
>
> My wife and I are adamantly opposed to persons and groups that have outwardly supported President Trump either during the election or the current administration. My wife believes that Chris Pratt has spoken out in support of Trump, though I've been unable to verify it. I have found things to suggest that he's a proud Republican, but nothing specific to support Trump.
>
> Are there any quotes, videos, or other situations where Chris Pratt has directly supported President Trump?

Comment: Can you link to the question? It's a bit difficult to say anything meaningful if we can't see the question

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Not sure if you'll be able to read that considering it was deleted and might only be visible to me.

Comment: Users with more than 2,000 reputation can see all deleted content (questions and answers), but for questions we need a direct link. You could also add a screenshot for <2k reputation users.

Answer (score 9):

I think that questions about the political opinions of celebrities are usually not on-topic. Truth is, that they usually don't matter much for political processes. This question in particular doesn't seem to aim to gain a better understanding of politics and political processes (as by our site definition), but rather about gaining a better understanding of Chris Pratt, a movie actor.

I think we might make exceptions, though, for celebrities who are particularly known for *serious* political activism. This should be more than just stating who they are going to vote for in an interview. I am thinking of people like [Charlton Heston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlton_Heston#Political_activism) (former NRA president) or [Ian McKellen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_McKellen#LGBT_activism) (LGBT rights activist).

And by the way, your question might have fared a tad better if you had avoided to state your opinion about a specific politician so clearly. We are a Q&A website, not a discussion forum. Putting your personal views into the foreground is usually a downvote-magnet, no matter on which side of the political spectrum they are. It is usually more popular here if you try to write your questions from a neutral point of view.

Regarding re-posting this question on Skeptics.SE: "Did Person X make statement Y" questions are on-topic there, but keep in mind that Skeptics requires that some **notable source** made the claim that X made statement Y. "This article by news website with considerable reach" or "this interview with well-known celebrity" counts as a notable source. "My wife believes" doesn't count.

Comment: I'd say that questions in the form of "Did <notable-person> X support candidate Y?" are always off-topic, regardless of the social activism reputation of <notable-person>. It's not just trivia fluff, it's also a yes/no question.

Comment: Endorsements are a long standing and important part of politics and the people who endorse a candidate shed light on a candidate. Indeed, modern political science recognizes the pivotal role that endorsements play in making decisions with limited information.