# When is question about concrete person's political views off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Based on comments on the question: [Has Sergei Lukyanenko revealed something about his political opinions since 2012](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/36048/has-sergei-lukyanenko-revealed-something-about-his-political-opinions-since-2012?noredirect=1#comment143285_36048).

> [image: Comments]

Questions about public people are **probably** sometimes on topic.

I mean, if somebody asked what Trump's, or Merkel's opinion is, it makes sense.

On the other hand, if somebody asked what is his friend's opinion, it is off topic, right?

---

**But I came up with some groups where I am not sure:**

- Less known politics.
- What about writers or actors (they have an influence on the people and therefore also on voting)?
- Businesspeople?
- University teachers?
- Politologists?
- People that run in elections (but they're not elected yet)?
- People that don't run in elections, but there is a good chance they will? (maybe in near future)

In fact, I am asking:

### **Where is the borderline?**

Comment: Related question: [How should I ask a question regarding a celebrity's political stance?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/how-should-i-ask-a-question-regarding-a-celebritys-political-stance). I responded to that question with my criteria for when I would consider the political opinions of a celebrity to be relevant on this website. Unfortunately everything I know about Lukyanenko is what I just read in the Wikipedia article about him, so I can not really judge if he can be considered a serious political activist.

Comment: @Philipp - It's Russia. The authors there were always "political activists" in a way (the same way musicians tend to be in the West, but to far greater degree). Quoting Yevtushenko, "[A poet in Russia is more than a poet](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/2206/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82)”. But Lukyanenko is not a political activist in a formal way - just an uber popular science fiction writer whose books have pretty heavy swings into political philosophy and who's pretty open about his views on some things.

Comment: I'm a little disappointed because I was hoping this would be about a person who's body is made of concrete.