# Should 'What has Russian world chess champion Boris Spassky said about Putin, the invasion, etc?' have been deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, deleted-questions

**Note**: I heard downvotes in a yes/no question in a meta post are a 'no' answer.

---

1st question: Why deleted?

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74692/what-has-russian-world-chess-champion-boris-spassky-said-about-putin-the-invasi

It had 2 of the 4 required re-open votes. And it had 4 upvotes vs 8 downvotes.

Roger Vadim said:

> I think the opinion of Spassky is no less relevant that, e.g., the opinion of Garry Kasparov, who is regularly quoted in the media. They obviously represent different kinds of opposition to Putin - Kasparov is a mainstream liberal democrat, while Spassky (as we see from the quote) is a monarchist. Non-liberal opposition views are even more relevant, if we remember that the main opposition force in Russia are still communists

2nd question:

Fizz said (in reply to the question whether he agrees with a vote to reopen)

> Yeah, I disagree. It's a hilariously bad false equivalence. Spassky isn't getting coverage because he's probably not saying much due to his health. There are plenty of healthy and active Russian celebrities that are openly pro-Putin and pro-war. And they get Western press coverage. (See Karjakin if you want to stick to chess or the conductor Gergiev etc.) But I see no reason to have a question about what each and every celebrity says about the war because the community decided celebrity focused questions are O/T. You can ask what the communists or imperial-revivalists said, more generally.

Roger Vadim said

> @Fizz It's a hilariously bad false equivalence. - I flagged your comment, because personal attacks violate SE policy. I suggest that you adopt more neutral language - 100k reputation obliges.

Was Fizz indeed doing a personal attack to Roger Vadim?

Comment: Just because the media quotes someone doesn't mean they are a political figure and relevant on politics se

Comment: @JoeW Was Fizz indeed doing a personal attack to Roger Vadim?

Comment: @JoeW What is difference between Garry Kasparov and Boris Spassky?

Comment: Please don't spam a person with comments. As for the differences we are not talking about a question about someone else but the question you are asking about. If you feel that another question has been asked about someone who is not a political figure you should flag/vote to close it to help prevent future confusion.

Comment: Meta is normally not used to resolve disputes between users. In this case I'll leave it up because Fizz already posted an answer discussing their position and your broader meta question is about whether the question should be deleted or not. As for that comment, I don't see how it's a personal attack because it refers to the comparison of Spassky and Kasparov.

Comment: Downvotes on meta mean disagreement. The obvious intent of the post is to argue the post should not be deleted, by questioning in an oppositional sense the reasons for deletion, therefore downvotes here signify it should not be not deleted, i.e. **the post should be deleted**. Deliberately naming a thing in one way and then letting it act in the opposite manner is not a tactic usually welcomed in honest debate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What else did I say about this, before ultimately voting to delete (for the benefit of those with less rep who can't read the deleted stuff)...

> Unlike Kasparov, Spassky doesn't seem to have had any direct involvement in political movements. Mere political opinions of celebrities is generally off topic here. [How should I ask a question regarding a celebrity's political stance?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/how-should-i-ask-a-question-regarding-a-celebritys-political-stance)
>
> Even Russian Wikipedia doesn't have any news of Spassky in almost a decade, since he suffered two strokes, but he did seemingly recover from those.
>
> Putin gave Spassky an award in 2017, but there's no mention of an official ceremony, so I'm guessing it wasn't in person.
>
> Most recent interview with Spassky I could [find](https://chess24.com/en/read/news/boris-spassky-i-m-waging-a-war) is from 2016. The only war he volunteered to discuss wss the one with his wife.
>
> And the same is true for a (much longer) [interview in Russian](https://www.sport-express.ru/fridays/reviews/973473/) ... although in the latter he also mentions Americans tried to use X-rays against him ... or something like that.
>
> He just wasn't that interested in discussing politics. He does mention that he left the USSR because the Soviet committees were preventing him from travelling, i.e. declining invitations to foreign events on his behalf (without asking him). He does get to his monarchist views and his interst in reading books about that period specifically some by [Nikolai Starikov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolai_Starikov), but doesn't really discuss any post-Soviet politics.
>
> So, yeah, despite you and Roger's protestations to the contrary, I'm really not seeing how Spassky is remotely a political activist or much of an influencer in that regard. Asking about the views of Starikov on the other hand, or the various parties he joined or founded may be much more on-topic (given his Ru wikipedia page).

Kasparov at least tried to run for presidency in Russia. And is willing to talk about present-day politics at lengths when interviewed. So, yeah, Spassky is the wrong exponent of anything more political here. Unless you want to play some Nixon card and have us guess what the silent monarchists in Russia are thinking.

FWTW, I also mentioned in comments that if you want to dig chess grandmasters who expressed their [full support](https://chess24.com/en/read/news/sergey-karjakin-banned-from-chess-for-6-months-over-ukraine-stance) for the "special military operation" that isn't too hard either, e.g. Karjakin... but (in hindsight) I see you probably
[already knew](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/74135/what-does-donbass-whom-the-ukrainian-army-has-been-bombing-for-the-last-8-year) that bit.

Comment: Is the question never retroactively on-topic if hypothetically tomorrow Boris would say something REGARDLESS of what Boris says?

Comment: @BCLC: is it possible you run for presidency tomorrow? It's possible. Are your views on-topic for Qs here until then? No, in my opinion.

Comment: ok fine. not sure i agree but at least you addressed the garry thing.