# My question was deleted from front page

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I have a question about my Politics Stack Exchange post: [what was Freddie mercury's religion?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/76394/what-was-freddie-mercurys-religion)

I have posted the aforementioned question yesterday and was deleted. Critics claimed that the post was off-topic but I strongly disagree.

Religion and politics are historically heavily related if not inseparable. In a sense of decoding world history inevitable and vital procedure for further findings, my post had a significant importance in developing further discussion on Politics Stack Exchange. The whole due process lacks rational basis:

> How is this related to politics? –
> convert
> 13 hours ago

> I don't see how this is related to anything, in all honesty. It looks like machine-generated gibberish. –
> F1Krazy
> 12 hours ago

Thus I protest to the deliberate action taken by the users who deleted it.

Comment: Related meta-question: [How should I ask a question regarding a celebrity's political stance?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/how-should-i-ask-a-question-regarding-a-celebritys-political-stance)

Comment: Freddie Mercury's religion is not a political topic, insofar as you give zero political relevance to it. Just because something is generally sometimes related to another thing, does not mean every instance of each is connected or topical.

Comment: Freddie Mercury is not even a polititian.

Answer (score 11):

I'm sorry that you had such a negative experience with your first question. However, I agree with the question being closed and deleted. There is more than one reason why it wasn't a good fit for the site:

1. Freddie Mercury was a musician, not a politician. And he didn't engage in much political activism. That means his political views aren't on-topic here. See also: [How should I ask a question regarding a celebrity's political stance?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/how-should-i-ask-a-question-regarding-a-celebritys-political-stance)
2. Even if he *had* been a relevant politician or political activist, his religious views would probably not be relevant. He was mostly popular in a culture where state and religion are separated.
3. The first three sentences "Write in such a way that the marker can see that you understand the content of the material. Next, add any insights you have gained from your own study. Then add your own findings from your own study." sound like a homework assignment. We are not going to do your homework for you.
4. You phrased it not as a question but as a discussion prompt. But this community is not a discussion forum. It's a question&answer website. Questions which do not have "correct answers or right answers" or ask us to "discuss this [thing]" are not a good fit for the Question&Answer concept of Stack Exchange.
5. The question already contains the answer. ("Freddie Mercury's religion is Zoroastrianism") That makes me wonder why you asked the question at all.
6. It has severe formatting problems. It's a wall of text with no paragraphs and weirdly jumps from thought to thought. The description by one commentator "It looks like machine-generated gibberish" doesn't seem too far-fetched to me.

For more information on how to use this site, please check out the resources we have on the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help). Specifically the article [What topics can I ask about here?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

It is a common misunderstanding to think that this site is about anything that is, or may potentially be, related to politics.  In fact, despite its name, its scope is more limited.

It's good that you took the 1st step of actually asking "what is wrong?"  But now that you took that 1st step, I would also recommend that you take a look through the answer provided by the mod.  It also has some references on where you can read more about what is or isn't in scope.

Answer (score 2):

Since I was one of the users, who voted to close, going to give an answer. Secularism is common for the most modern political systems, not just democrtic ones, so mixing politics and religion is incorect. However the main and really relevant reason for my decision for vote to close is what you can read if taking a tour:

> Don't ask about...
>
> ```
> Anything not directly related to governments, policies and political processes
> Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer
> ```

The first point should explain it.