# Is someone like Arestovich on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Oleksii Arestovych](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oleksii_Arestovych) has held a number of roles in Ukraine.  The most visible of them is probably as a spokesman for the office of the President of Ukraine.  The highest ranking is probably as an independent consultant to the Chief of Staff of the office of the President of Ukraine.  He is a fairly colorful character who was also a very prolific commentator on Russia's war against Ukraine.

Technically, he is not a politician anymore though.

So I am not sure if questions about him as blogger, or as a media/advocacy personality, are on topic.

Comment: Related question (but IMO not a duplicate): [How should I ask a question regarding a celebrity's political stance?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/how-should-i-ask-a-question-regarding-a-celebritys-political-stance/)

Comment: Can you perhaps be a bit more specific about what kind of questions you would ask about him? "How did he get fired from his advisor position?" -> on-topic. "What is his favorite brand of soda?" -> off-topic. Something in between? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Philipp he is generally seen more as a political operative than as a celebrity.

Comment: Maybe he can be put in the same category as [Valery Solovey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valery_Solovei) on the Russian side - someone who used to have a great deal of access, but who is currently out of favor with the power directly, although appears to have a lot of back channel access and who comments on the events based on his background and on his presumed back channel access.

Answer (score 9):

It is going to depend on what is being asked about. If you are asking about him in his political activities it would be on topic. however if you are asking in regards to his commentator role it might not be on topic.

Comment: His commentary is on politics and history of warfare.  He is (probably legitimately) often accused of changing his views too frequently.  And yet he was at the center of many of the events in Ukraine during this war.  He is probably one of the 5 most visible people on the Ukrainian side.

Comment: @wrod That is why I said it depends on what is being asked about and how his commentator role "Might" not be on topic. I didn't say it wasn't on topic, just suggested that it might not be.

Comment: I wasn't really arguing.  Just pondering.